# postgres copy command - fields enclosed with double quotes with comma and separated by comma in csv file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5

i am facing data import issue postgres table. i have data in csv file like.

> "this", "postgres,sql", "linux","infile","that", "post,sql", "lnux","file"

i tried to import data using below command but it is giving error

> \copy test_table FROM '/home/postgres/testdata/testfile.csv' WITH
>      DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
>
> ERROR:  extra data after last expected column

so how to eliminate extra comma in double quotes.

Comment: Have you tried `\COPY test_table FROM 'testfile.csv' DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '"' HEADER CSV` ?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with commas. The line you quote has 8 fields, and that seems to be more than `test_table` has.

Comment: i tried \COPY test_table FROM 'testfile.csv' DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '"' HEADER CSV this command  and i am getting error "unterminated CSV quoted field".

Comment: @VittalCherala then you should check your csv file for an error